Alternatives to ST_CONTAINS via Uber's H3
ST_CONTAINS returns TRUE if geometry A contains geometry B. A contains B if and only if all points of B lie inside (i.e. in the interior or boundary of) A (or equivalently, no points of B lie in the exterior of A), and the interiors of A and B have at least one point in common. It is a predicate in postgis, but it is very slow when creating a table or mat view.
I see H3 Uber has maxPolyfillSize but I cannot see an example as an alternative. Any ideas?
I know this is no code it is a very specific question, sorry in advance if that bothers.

did you create any spatial index? And do you have a query plan, using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your unknown SQL statement?

@FrankHeikens the query is far to long to copy into stackoverflow as the explain . Yes there is a spatial index, it comes down to just the use of st_contains that is impacting runtime. Mind, I am speaking about a materialized view (or create table as) statement , not returning data from a view or table yet creating one.

You could also post the content at https://explain.depesz.com and just link to that result.

@FrankHeikens very cool, thank you ! here is link https://explain.depesz.com/s/ms43

Rows Removed by Filter is all over the place, looks like you need some changes in your current indexes or new indexes. two_papa_uniform and alpha_golf stand out, check these first.

@FrankHeikens out of curiosity, i do feel like these relate to st_contains - why did you not address that? Not that I don't appreciate the response, just curious?

Because the query plan isn't great at all. Right now the index scan on kilo_sierra is the slowest part, a better query plan might improve that part. Second, because of the obfuscation the query plan is pretty hard to read or understand. I think juliet_juliet() is the function st_contains(), that one also filters out a lot of data, without using an index: Rows Removed by Join Filter: 40023

@FrankHeikens sorry to delay and thank yo so much the above helped but simply put I need more help -- is there any chance you'd be open to a direct message style of communication or just further stack overflow posts?

You can contact me directly
